# What JSON parser does Django Fixture Loading Use

Tags: python, json, django, unit-testing

My Django unit tests are quite slow. I'm using in-memory sqlite and keeping fixtures to a minimum. However it still takes about 5 seconds to load a fixture.

I've read json fixtures are faster than yaml ones and am therefore using json.

My suspicion is that the fixtures are using a slow json library (json or simplejson instead of cjson).

My questions are these:

- Can anyone confirm the fixture loading is the slow part or have an
  idea on how to go about this?
- Does anyone know what json library django uses to load fixtures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django fixtures are loaded using [`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) management command which uses built-in django [deserializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#deserializing-data) which [use](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/json.py#L11) [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module from the standard library.

Fixtures are slow and difficult to maintain. Consider using model factories instead. Basically, there are two major players out there:

- [`factory_boy`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [`model_mommy`](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy)

Also see:

- [On Fixtures and Factories](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/fixtures-and-factories/)
- [Factory Boy as an Alternative to Django Testing Fixtures](http://jeffammons.net/2011/10/converting-django-tests-to-use-factory-boy/)

Comment: It appears the json parser takes only about 10% of the time. The majority of the time is spent turning the parsed json into Django objects:json: 0.0230231285095 deserializer: 0.242472887039 total: 0.265496015549
json: 0.0223681926727 deserializer: 0.253935813904 total: 0.276304006577
json: 0.108466148376 deserializer: 0.732606887817 total: 0.841073036194
json: 0.00613403320312 deserializer: 0.0740101337433 total: 0.0801441669464
json: 1.38954401016 deserializer: 25.5058369637 total: 26.8953809738

Comment: @bbrame yeah, thanks, in case of model factories - you would create model objects directly in the python code.